# Squatting App ID?

Tags: app-store

I just registered the app id "com.rovio.angrybirds2" in the provisioning portal of my Apple developer account (out of curiosity). Does this mean that Rovio can't acquire com.rovio.angrybirds2?

Why is this allowed?

Comment: You can do it, but you have 90 to actually upload an App. After 90 days, you will lose rights to that App ID.

Answer (score 0):

When registering an app name, if my memory is right, you have 3 months to upload a binary or the app name will be deleted and free again.

apart from this, Rovio is just a phone call away from deleting your app if you had the chance of submitting it and getting approved by the apple team.

I wouldn't play this, you could get your dev account blocked or suspended, I think it clearly goes against apple policies of app's approval (that you can find in iTunes Connect.

[app review resources link](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/appreview.html)

quote : "If you attempt to cheat the system (for example, by trying to trick the review process, steal data from users, copy another developer's work, or manipulate the ratings) your apps will be removed from the store and you will be expelled from the developer program."

Comment: Just to make it clear, my intention wasn't to upload an Angry Birds clone or screw Rovio over. I wanted to see if Rovio had another Angry Birds in the pipeline.

Comment: @Ninja : they call their product "angry birds", "angry birds seasons", "angry birds rio", "angry birds space".. not angry birds 1, 2, 3, 4.. ;)

Comment: @moxy: who knows, Angry Birds 2 could be a completely new game rather than minor gameplay additions + levels.

Comment: BTW, aren't App Names and App ID different? does the 3 months rule apply to App ID?